# How to get hierarchy of employees

Tags: mysql

I was trying to get the hierarchy of employees for manager id .I could do that for known level. But i want the entire level associates in that hierarchy. My table is like this.

```
    Super_id  EmployeeId

    10        30
    10        28
    10        16
    16        34
    16        45
    45        67
    45        36
    24        69
    24        76
```

I will pass 10 as parameter : output should be 30,28,16,34,45,67,36

I am not expecting a single query .I can use Stored procedure /functions too.

Comment: what should be the output here?

Comment: I will pass 10 as parameter : output should be 30,28,16,34,45,67,36

Answer (score 0):

This is only possible by either using a stod procedure on the database or by querying multiple times for for your application. I you have a fixed number of hierarchy levels, you can perform that many self joins but it is not possible to get a full tree using SQL from only parent pointers.

However there exist two common techniques for implemting this. One is called [Nested Set model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) and uses a representation of sets for each level defined by a left and right boundary. The second variant is that of a materialized path. With this variant, you specify the full path for each element (which you then have to update on each change in one of the parents)

Each if the techniques has its unique pros and cons. It is now up to you to decide which one you can use of your specific area.